# @typeform/embed breaks Gatsby Netlify build

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, package.json, netlify, typeform

I've followed the typeform embed directions and even switch to yarn package manager as they recommend but I keep getting an error in the build.

```
5:27:38 PM: failed Building static HTML for pages - 4.592s

5:27:38 PM: error Building static HTML failed


5:27:38 PM: > 1 | !function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t(require("react"),require("react-dom")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["react","react-dom"],t):"object"==typeof exports?
```

That error goes on and on.

However, as soon as I stop importing typeform I don't have any issues.
This line is the culprit.

```
import * as typeformEmbed from "@typeform/embed";
```

If I get rid of that and just return an empty div I don't have any issues.

Here is the entire component

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import * as typeformEmbed from "@typeform/embed";

const Form = () => {
    const typeformRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        typeformEmbed.makeWidget(
            typeformRef.current,
            "https://tu6s6xuakuw.typeform.com/to/wGd96IFk",
            {
                hideFooter: true,
                hideHeaders: true,
                opacity: 50,
            }
        );
    }, [typeformRef]);

    return (
        <div ref={typeformRef} style={{ height: "500px", width: "100%" }}></div>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

Any leads on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this happening only when you run `gatsby build`? My first thought is that perhaps the Typeform embed SDK references the `window` object somewhere, which is not available at build time with Gatsby. This is a fairly common gotcha with Gatsby and has some [guidance in the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#how-to-check-if-window-is-defined). Worth a go if you haven't tried it yet. Nothing immediately sticks out as being wrong with your component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following snippet in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === 'build-html') {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({ 
            module: {
                rules: [
                  {
                    test: /@typeform/,
                    use: loaders.null(),
                  },
                ],
              }
        })
    }
}
```

When dealing with third-party modules that use `window` in Gatsby you need to add a `null` loader to its own webpack configuration to avoid the transpilation during the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering). This is because `gatsby develop` occurs in the browser while `gatsby build` occurs in the Node server where obviously there isn't a [`window` or other global objects](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

Keep in mind that the `test` value is a regular expression that will match a folder under `node_modules` so, ensure that the `/@typeform/` is the right name (you may need to change it to `/@typeform/\embed/`).